# Vertex merging in graph?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

### Context

Given a [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graph.html)  such as the one produced with the following code

```
 u = GaussianRandomField[n = 16, 2, Function[k, 1/k^2 Exp[-1/40 k^2]]] // Chop;
 skl = Map[If[# == 0, 1, 0] &, u // Image // WatershedComponents, {2}] // SparseArray;
 skl2 = arrayGraph[Normal@skl, VertexSize -> 0.4, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]];
 HighlighVertexDegree[skl2, VertexDegree[skl2]]
```

which is available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/659996/graph.m)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Question

> I would like
>
> - to merge all groups of two (or more) yellow  vertices by one single vertex which should have as a position their center of mass (I have highlighted them with ellipses by hand on this example).

For this second goal (which I should have posted as an independent question) the idea would be to write a function, say, `SmoothGraph` so that when given a graph, would return
 the same graph but with [`VertexCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexCoordinates.html) modified for all the light yellow points so as to provide a smoother version.

PS: The yellow vertices are those which vertex degree is equal to two.

PS: these are the codes I used to produce the above graph

```
   arrayGraph[mat_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{m = Module[{i = 1}, mat /. 1 :> i++], edges, vcs, v}, 
  v = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Label"][[All, 1]];
  vcs = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Centroid", CornerNeighbors -> False];  
  edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ 
  DeleteDuplicates[
  Sort /@ Flatten[Thread /@  ComponentMeasurements[m, "Neighbors", 
     CornerNeighbors -> False]]];
  Graph[v, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcs, opts]]

  HighlighVertexDegree[g_, vd_] := 
  HighlightGraph[g, 
  Table[Style[VertexList[g][[i]], 
  ColorData["TemperatureMap"][vd[[i]]/Max[vd]]], {i, VertexCount[g]}]];


  GaussianRandomField[size : (_Integer?Positive) : 256, dim : (_Integer?Positive) : 2,
                    Pk_: Function[k, k^-3]] := Module[{Pkn, fftIndgen, noise, amplitude, s2},
  Pkn = Compile[{{vec, _Real, 1}}, With[{nrm = Norm[vec]},
                                        If[nrm == 0, 0, Sqrt[Pk[nrm]]]], 
                CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
  s2 = Quotient[size, 2];
  fftIndgen = ArrayPad[Range[0, s2], {0, s2 - 1}, "ReflectedNegation"];
  noise = Fourier[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], ConstantArray[size, dim]]]; 
  amplitude = Outer[Pkn[{##}] &, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[N @ fftIndgen, dim]];
  InverseFourier[noise * amplitude]]
```

### Attempt

Following @Öskå  advice I computed the candidates vertices as follows

```
 cand = EdgeList[skl2, # <-> _] & /@ 
 Flatten[(Position[VertexDegree[skl2], 3])];
 cand2 = Flatten[cand /. UndirectedEdge[a_, b_] -> {a, b}] // Sort;
 cand3 = First /@ Select[Tally[cand2], #[[2]] > 3 &]
```

(* {6,7,8,20,21,29,30,31,51,56,85,93,97,102,106,107,108} *)

Indeed we can check they are correctly identified

```
  skl4 = HighlighVertexDegree[skl2, VertexDegree[skl2]];
  skl4=Graph[skl4, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For your last question, take a look at `VertexInComponent[g, yourVertex, 1]`

Comment: @chris, this is an interesting problem but can you extract a minimal example, eg with a single vertex cluster?

Comment: When I arrive your **Dropbox**,it warns me a [error information](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iG4Pz.png).

Comment: @yode Dropbox changed its policy unfortunately

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to write function to set new coord and new edge shape function.

Here's one example to do such things:

```
mergeVertex[g_, set_List] :=     
 Block[{vcoord, ids, ncoord, ng, newv, nedge, endp, oedge, pind, 
   neshape},
  vcoord = GraphEmbedding[g];
  ids = {VertexIndex[g, #]} & /@ set;
  ncoord = Join[Delete[vcoord, ids], {Mean[Extract[vcoord, ids]]}];

  ng = VertexContract[g, set];
  newv = Last[VertexList[ng]];
  nedge = EdgeList[ng, newv <-> _];

  neshape = Table[
    endp = If[e[[1]] == newv, e[[2]], e[[1]]];
    oedge = First[EdgeList[g, endp <-> _?(MemberQ[set, #] &)]];
    pind = 
     If[oedge[[1]] == endp, VertexIndex[g, oedge[[2]]], 
      VertexIndex[g, oedge[[1]]]];
    With[{v = vcoord[[pind]]}, 
     e -> (BezierCurve[{#[[1]], v, #[[-1]]}] &)]
    ,
    {e, nedge}];
  neshape = 
   Join[neshape, 
    EdgeShapeFunction /. 
      Options[g, EdgeShapeFunction] /. {Automatic -> {}}];

  Graph[VertexList[ng], EdgeList[ng], EdgeShapeFunction -> neshape, 
   VertexCoordinates -> ncoord, 
   FilterRules[Options[g], {EdgeStyle, VertexSize}]]
  ]
```

### Example:

Compute candidates:

```
cand = Select[
  ConnectedComponents[
   Subgraph[skl2, 
    VertexList[skl2, x_ /; (VertexDegree[skl2, x] == 3)]]], 
  Length[#] > 1 &]
```

> {{80, 81, 85, 86}, {45, 46, 57, 58}, {39, 40, 41}, {75, 76}}

original graph:

```
HighlightGraph[HighlighVertexDegree[skl2, VertexDegree[skl2]], cand, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Merge vertices by group:

```
g = Fold[mergeVertex, skl2, cand];
HighlighVertexDegree[g, VertexDegree[g]]
```

[image]