# Better layout for large a directed graph?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

This shows a directed graph for an iterated `n`-bit pseudo-random function parameterized by `s`.

```
n = 7; s = "bar"; m = 2^n;
Graph[Table[i -> Mod[Hash[s<>ToString[i], "SHA1"], m], {i, 0, m-1}]]
```

How can I improve its layout, in particular

- with better use of the available area (currently overwhelmingly unused)
- without occasional spurious vertex crossing (there's one on the right of this particular graph, where I added a tiny red circle)
- perhaps with the cycles automatically distinguished, as [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24638/555)?
- otherwise nicer and usable for larger `n` (update: say `n = 15`)?

[image: sample graph]

Comment: I really like the solution to a related problem I posed:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69555/intelligent-vertex-placement-in-large-tree-graphs

Comment: how large you want to go?