# How to Optimize Solution? (Project Euler #14)

Tags: performance-tuning, project-euler

Link to Question: https://projecteuler.net/problem=14

I began by defining the following functions below.

```
collatz := If[EvenQ[#], #/2, 3 # + 1] &
NotOneQ := collatz[#] != 1 &
collatzlength := Plus[NestWhileList[collatz, #, NotOneQ] // Length, 1] &
```

To find the actual answer, I inputted

```
Min[
 Flatten[
  Position[
   Table[collatzlength[i], {i, 1, 999999}], 
   Max[Table[collatzlength[i], {i, 1, 999999}]]]]]
```

> ```
> 837799
> ```

Basically, it computes `collatzlength` for `i = 1` to `i = 999999`, Tabled the results into a list, found the Position(s) of the maximum value in the list, and (in case there were multiple numbers with the same Collatz sequence length) took the minimum entry from a Flattened list.

Though this solution is simple and conceptually intuitive, it is fairly primitive and took a whopping **16 minutes** for *Mathematica* to evaluate. How can I optimize this solution to make it compute faster? I saw other posts on StackExchange asking the same thing for Problem #14, but I was unable to understand any of the concepts discussed in those posts.

Thanks for reading,

-A

Edit: I tried the suggestion below about memorization. Here is the setup. Please let me know if it is incorrect and what needs to be changed. Please refer to the top of the post for the original function definitions.

```
f[x__] := collatz[x] = If[EvenQ[x], x/2, 3 x + 1]
g[x__] := f[x] != 1
h[x__] := collatzlength[x] = Plus[NestWhileList[f, x, g] // Length, 1]
```

The adjusted input was then

```
Min[Flatten[
  Position[Table[h[i], {i, 1, 999999}], 
   Max[Table[h[i], {i, 1, 999999}]]]]]
```

I tested both methods using `{i,1,10000}` and `AbsoluteTiming`, and the computation time more than doubled after the memorizations were applied. Here are the results.

Original:

> ```
> {21.303, 6171}
> ```

Memorizations applied:

> ```
> {42.7376, 6171}
> ```

Comment: Maybe memoize the functions?  The usual syntax is something like this:  `f[x_] := f[x] = rhs`  The first time you call f[3], it will evaluate the rhs and assign that to f[3].  Next time you call f[3], it merely fetches the value from memory and skips evaluating the rhs a second time.  If your program makes many redundant calls, this should save a lot of time.

Comment: I tried this, and the computation time nearly doubled, unfortunately. I will post what I changed. It doesn't make sense that computation time would increase, so I most likely set it up incorrectly.

Comment: search for "collatz" in this site. There are several related questions.

Comment: No. Just change, e.g., first line to `collatz[x_] := collatz[x] = If[EvenQ[x], x/2, 3 x + 1]`, see what happens. Figure out if any other memoization might apply. And note *belisarius*'s comment - there are smart ways to do this.

Comment: Related (with some beautiful visualizations): [(85718)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85718/trying-to-visualize-a-collatz-the-collatz-conjecture)

Answer (score 2):

The performance can be further increased by just calculating and memoizing the sequence length and using `ParallelMap` instead of `Map`.

```
seqLength[1] = 1

seqLength[n_?EvenQ] := seqLength[n] = 1 + seqLength[n/2]
seqLength[n_?OddQ] := seqLength[n] = 1 + seqLength[3 n + 1]

lengthList = Flatten@ParallelMap[seqLength, Range[10^6], Method -> Automatic];
Position[lengthList, Max@lengthList]
```

Comment: Nice approach to save memory, +1

Answer (score 1):

I figured, that the performance increase of memoizing the result of `a_?OddQ -> 3 a + 1` or `a_?EvenQ -> a / 2` would hardly help. However, it would be very helpful to memoize the sequence from applying the rule all the way until the result goes down to 1.

Like so:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[1] = {1};
f[a_?EvenQ] := f[a] = Join[{a}, f[a/2]]
f[a_?OddQ] := f[a] = Join[{a}, f[3 a + 1]]

AbsoluteTiming[f /@ Range[999 999]] // First
```

> ```
> 16.3734
> ```

Looks like those 16 minutes turned into 16 seconds.

```
Length /@ (f /@ Range[999 999]);
Max@%
```

> ```
> 525
> ```

```
Position[%%, 525]
```

> ```
> {{837 799}}
> ```

```
f[837 799] // Short
```

> ```
> {837799,2513398,1256699,3770098,1885049,5655148,2827574,<<511>>,10,5,16,8,4,2,1}
> ```