# Computing, rendering and exporting humongous graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I need to compute, lay out, and export humongous graphs with, say, $3 \cdot 10^6$ nodes.  I have a number of such graphs but as a specific case you can see an example (including source code) for the [Collatz Conjecture](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85718/trying-to-visualize-the-collatz-conjecture).  For my current hardware (Mac Pro desktop, 22GB hard memory) I can rendering graphs up to $|V| = 4 \cdot 10^5$ nodes and export them as a pdf.  I can algorithmically compute the graph in *portions* and algorithmically merge the portions.  (This approach is most reasonable for weakly connected graphs, such as the Collatz graph.)  The problem is then that the `GraphEmbedding` is inconsistent.  I want a *single* `GraphEmbedding` (such as `GraphLayout -> {"PackingLayout" -> "ClosestPacking"}` to apply to the *full* graph, and applying `ClosestPacking` on a few dozen portions of the graph will not yield the entire graph in a unified embedding.

How can I render the Collatz graph up to $3 \cdot 10^6$ nodes, lay it out in a unified embedding, and export it (for use in *Adobe Illustrator* or $\LaTeX$, for instance)?