# Generating and rendering extremely large graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, memory

I'm interested in generating and rendering extremely large graphs, i.e., ones having $10^6 \to 10^8$ vertices.  (These graphs will ultimately be rendered in PDF or PNG and printed on large, poster-sized paper.)  Although the code may work for small graphs, there are inevitably limitations for large graphs due to computer memory (especially when embedding or laying-out the graph, as we'll see).

Consider the small graph generated by the [Collatz conjecture](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85718/trying-to-visualize-the-collatz-conjecture) with 400000 nodes (see code below, based on the cited problem):

[image: 400000 node Collatz graph]

where the `GraphLayout -> {"PackingLayout" -> "ClosestPacking"}`.  This can be computed directly on a Mac laptop.  But for larger numbers of vertices, the graph cannot be rendered.

Note especially that this is just a representative graph... I need a solution for many different large graphs, ones without simple geometric structure.

The problem arises when one wants to generate and lay out (or "embed") $10^7$ vertices.  The problem is not so much the computation of the vertices and edges (which can be done by writing to a large external file), but instead *laying out* the graph.  The `Layout` nominally needs all the vertexes in active memory in order to perform the layout, and that is impossible on most machines.

[I've closed all other applications to provide *Mathematica* with the maximum memory, but even this is not enough for the large graphs I wish to render.  Perhaps this entire problem is solved by moving the enormous computation to the Wolfram Cloud... and if this is the case, I guess I'll merely purchase an account and run my code there.  But I'm hoping there is a better way... one that can be used on laptops and desktop machines (with large hard memories).]

One might try to layout *portions* of the overall graph and then "glue" them together, but the local optimization of layout of each portion is likely not appropriate for the full graph:  Different branches will ultimately overlap, breaking the rule of the global optimization routine.

My idea is to generate the enormous graph $G$ (but not lay it out).  Then select some small *random* subset of the vertexes, $V_1$, say 1% of those in $G$, to form a smaller, representative graph $G_1$ where the edges in $G_1$ are estimates of the "distance" between each vertex based on their step separation in $G$.  Then, layout this representative $G_1$ (which should be no problem because it is small).  Then, anchor the vertexes of $G_1$ in place in the final layout and then render *all* the vertexes of $G$.  In this way, the full, final graph $G$ is rendered appropriately, and the memory constraints are not exceeded.

Perhaps there is a way to extract VertexCoordinates and iteratively layout vertices in regions, hopping through the overall graph.  (This seems extremely inefficient.)

Or use smart memory management... or another technique.

---

```
CollatzSequence[list_] := 
  Module[{memory, tmp, chain, result = Internal`Bag[]},
   memory[1] = False;
   memory[n_] := (memory[n] = False; True);
   Do[chain = Internal`Bag[];
    tmp = l;
    While[memory[tmp], Internal`StuffBag[chain, tmp];
     tmp = If[EvenQ[tmp], tmp/2, 3 tmp + 1];];
    Internal`StuffBag[chain, tmp];
    Internal`StuffBag[result, chain], {l, list}];
   Internal`BagPart[#, All] & /@ Internal`BagPart[result, All]];

myCollatzGraph = Rasterize[
   Graph[Flatten[(Rule @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]) & /@ 
      CollatzSequence[Range[400000]]],
    GraphLayout -> {"PackingLayout" -> "ClosestPacking"},
    VertexStyle -> Opacity[0.2, RGBColor[.9, .1, .1]],
    EdgeStyle -> RGBColor[.1, .1, .9],
    ImageSize -> 2000],
   ImageResolution -> 72];
```

Comment: Isn't this graph a tree? That is what the Collatz conjecture states, right?  I mean, this _is_ a structure that one can try to exploit for rendering. Towards rendering: I am afraid that the ultimate constraint will be the poor 32-bit frontend that can render only graphics that are not too complex (or will crash)... One may circumvent the frontend by directly generating code for a vector graphics, though.

Comment: One additional potential trick would be to use `IGSmoothen` from IGraph/M, which replaced chains of edges as in `1->2->3->4->5` ... with a single weighted edge `1->5`. This would reduce the size of the graph by 5-6 fold, and the weights can be used to maintain the layout. However, I noticed that `IGSmoothen` is currently not fast enough. I will look into optimizing it. It should work much faster on graphs of this size.

Comment: Unbelievably, the IGSmoothen is slow for one single reason: `Delete` is slow.  I will fix this for the next release (due tonight).

Comment: In short, Mathematica is not the right tool for this. Use something that can be stopped and resumed on demand, and is designed to run for a very long time. Even with such tools, 10^8 is not a very reasonable size to try to visualize.

Comment: @Szabolcs:  Fair point.  But in *Mathematica* I can compute the link structure of any size network (e.g., $10^8$), writing the links (`a -> b, b-> c`, etc.) to external files and then link these up.  This might require some cleverness in finding the tree structure, but that is an *algorithmic* (not processing) problem.  So *that* portion of the work can be done.  As far as I can see, the layout (embedding) is the subproblem that is hard to perform in *Mathematica*.  Might analogous large problems have been mapped to memory architectures?  Will this work in the Wolfram cloud?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest *not* to use `Graph` to render, as it is slow. Instead, compute the vertex coordinates, then render manually.

The rough steps are as follows:

Create an "index graph", i.e. a graph where the vertex names coincide with the vertex indices:

```
n = 10000;
g = IndexGraph@Graph[
    Flatten[(Rule @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]) & /@ 
      CollatzSequence@Range[n]]
    ];
```

Compute the vertex coordinates:

```
coord = GraphEmbedding[g, "SpringElectricalEmbedding"];
```

This is going to be the most expensive step (computationally), but it will likely not take too much memory. Here, you will need to experiment to find a layout that produces a good enough result and finishes in time. `"SpringElectricalLayout"` will be slow, but it has many sub-options which can be used to find a good compromise between computation time and layout quality.  I would start experimenting with `Tolerance` and `MaxIteration`.

Finally, render the graphics:

```
Image@Graphics@GraphicsComplex[coord, Line[List @@@ EdgeList[g]]]
```

Be sure to use GraphicsComplex and merge all lines and all points into a single Line and Point expression. Finally, we rasterize the result so the front end does not need to keep the vector graphics representation in memory.

---

Example:

```
n = 400000;
g = IndexGraph@Graph[
    Flatten[(Rule @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]) & /@ 
      CollatzSequence@Range[n]]
    ];

VertexCount[g]
(* 869322 *)

coord = GraphEmbedding[
    g, {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "Tolerance" -> 1, 
     "MaxIteration" -> 5}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {48.8368, Null} *)

Image@Graphics@GraphicsComplex[coord, Line[List @@@ EdgeList[g]]]
```

[image]

```
Image@Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[
    coord, {Line[List @@@ EdgeList[g]], Red, AbsolutePointSize[1], 
     Point[coord]}]}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

The 32-bit macOS front end with absolutely not run out of memory while rendering graphics of this size, *if specified efficiently, as here*.

The bottleneck is the computation of coordinates, where you need to find a good compromise between computation time and output quality. This example took just under a minute on my machine. The time would likely stay under 5 minutes if MaxIteration is increased 5-fold (along with a reduction of Tolerance, which also put a limit on how many steps are computed).

---

Note:

I notice you used `GraphLayout -> {"PackingLayout" -> "ClosestPacking"}`. This makes no sense for a connected graph like this. The PackingLayout controls how connected components are assembled after each one has been laid out. This is a connected graph. It has only one component.

Comment: Thanks so very much (+1, at the very least).  Let me play around with your solution to see just how large a final graph I can create... whether I can reach the needed $10^8$ vertices.  I'm really not worried about *time*... just size.  I'd be happy indeed if this approach can render $10^8$ vertices, even if it took several hours on my hardware.  (Alas, I'm off to China in a few hours and won't get back to this for a few days...)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork [I just fixed IGSmoothen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/187206/12) and will try to expand on the answer later. It will be useful if you are fine with not explicitly rendering vertices (only edges). For such a large graph it often makes sense to omit vertices.

Comment: Your code didn't complete for $n=10^6$ after five hours.  Let me know if *IGSmoothen* works.  (I may be out of contact for a few days... but am *very* interested in a working solution to this problem.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You need to adjust the MaxIteration to get a good tradeoff between timing and quality. I suggest you also experiment with `IGLayoutFruchtermanReingold` from IGraph/M. It has an option to continue the layout from the existing coordinates. So you can run it a bit, take a look, and run more if needed.  I did not have time to do that, but here's one with IGSmoothen, today's IGraph/M release needed! https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwclsetrm89lkib/collatz-graph.nb?dl=0

Comment: I returned to this problem years later and found that Szabolcs' solution is a good as it gets (given the hardware constraints).  Thanks.  ($\checkmark$)