# Delete with multiple indices is extremely slow--workaround?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

[`Delete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html) is unbelievably slow when deleting *multiple* elements from a non-packed array.

Is there a robust workaround that will work on any non-packed array?

```
inds = List /@ RandomSample[Range[100000], 50000];
Delete[Developer`FromPackedArray@Range[100000], inds]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {17.8957, Null} *)
```

On packed arrays it performs as expected, but my array cannot be packed. It does not necessarily contain numbers.

```
inds = List /@ RandomSample[Range[100000], 50000];
Delete[Range[100000], inds]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.005767, Null} *)
```

---

I did not try to test for this, but one possible explanation is that even when given multiple indices, `Delete` will delete elements one-by-one, re-allocating the array after each step.  If someone feels like testing it, you can try to see if the timing is quadratic in the number of elements deleted.

Answer (score 14):

Exploiting the fact that Delete works fine on packed arrays, we can first construct an index vector, delete the unneeded indices, then finally use the remaining ones to index into the main array.

```
arr = Developer`FromPackedArray@Range[100000];
inds = List /@ RandomSample[Range[100000], 50000];

Part[arr, Delete[Range@Length[arr], inds]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.006371, Null} *)
```

Comment: Embarrassing for `Delete` that this method which ought to have terrible time complexity is so much faster... Have you tested some of the other things like delete on unpacked arrays?

Comment: @b3m2a1 I don't think that this has larger complexity... Still it is pretty bad that `Delete` is not clever enough to do that automatically. I'd suggest to inform Wolfram Support.

Answer (score 9):

Why not use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) assignment (to `Sequence[]`) instead?

```
arr = Developer`FromPackedArray@Range[100000];
inds = List /@ RandomSample[Range[100000],50000];

r1 = Part[arr, Delete[Range@Length[arr], inds]]; //RepeatedTiming
(r2 = arr; r2[[Flatten @ inds]] = Sequence[];) //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.0059, Null}
>
> {0.0019, Null}
>
> True

Comment: `Nothing` is slightly faster than `Sequence[]` on my laptop.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries and Carl, to fully reduce the array the procedure needs to be followed by `r2;`. Both Sequence and Nothing will now produce same timings as Part+Delete. p.s. to see what I mean try this: `r = {1, 2}; r[[1]] = Nothing; Information@r`