# Algorithmic graph embedding (layout) based on the values of adjacent vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to embed (layout) a tree graph where the angle of each edge is determined by a simple function of the values of the vertices that that edge joins as well as the previous edge angle.  An excellent application is the (binary) Collatz conjecture tree graph.

Here is [Collatz code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85718/trying-to-visualize-the-collatz-conjecture) that will form the Collatz tree graph.  The task is now to lay it out (embed it in the plane) based on the values of the vertices and the previous angle of an edge.

Here is a teeny portion of the Collatz graph:

```
Graph[{5 -> 16, 32 -> 16, 16 -> 8}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Suppose the angle of the 16 -> 8 edge happens to be vertical.  (More generally, an edge will be at some angle $\theta$.)  I would like the angle of any subsequent edge to vertex 16 will be at angle $\theta + \phi$ if it comes from an even-valued vertex, and $\theta - \phi$ if it comes from an odd-valued vertex.

[Here is a video of the final graph layout I'm seeking.](https://oli.me.uk/2017/04/04/the-collatz-conjecture-visualised-in-clojure/)

**Example**:

For the teeny portion of the Collatz graph, 5 -> 16 edge to be rotated by some angle $+\phi$ (e.g., $\theta+5^\circ$) and the 32 -> 16 edge to be rotated by $-\phi$ (e.g., $\theta-5^\circ$).

I'd like to create `VertexCoordinateRules` that involves the value of a linked vertex (even or odd) *and* the orientation of the adjacent edge.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2:** Another attempt:

`pos[{t1, t2, ...}, {u, v}]` gives the starting position `{x, y}` that connects to the final position `{u, v}`  if we follow the angle path `{t1, t2, ...}`. For a non-sink vertex `v` the path of angles is found by replacing the vertices on the shortest path from `v` to `1` with `ϕ + θ` or `ϕ - θ` depending on parity.

```
ClearAll[pos, angleList, vcoord]
pos[t:{__}, {u_, v_}] := {u, v} - Total[Through @ {Cos, Sin} @ Accumulate[t], {2}]
angleList[g_, v_, ϕ_, t_] := ϕ +  Most[FindShortestPath[g, v, 1]] /. 
   {u_?EvenQ -> t, u_?OddQ -> - t}
vcoord[g_, v_, ϕ_, t_, pos1_: {0, 0}] := pos[angleList[g, v, ϕ, t], pos1]
```

***Examples:***

```
vk = 20;
edges = (DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Collatz[#], 2, 1]) & /@ Range[vk] // Flatten // Union;
g = Graph[edges];
ϕ = 0;
θ = Pi/32;
Graph[edges, 
    VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {0, 0}, v_ :> vcoord[g, v, ϕ, θ]}, 
     ImagePadding -> 20, EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[Small], 
     VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", AspectRatio -> 2, 
     ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

With `vk = 500` and

```
Graph[edges, 
   VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {0, 0}, v_ :> vcoord[g, v, ϕ, θ]}, 
    ImagePadding -> 20, EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[Tiny], 
    VertexShapeFunction ->None, AspectRatio -> 2,   ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Using

```
VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {0, 0}, v_ :> vcoord[g, v, ϕ, 2 θ]}
```

[image]

With `vk = 600` and adding the options

```
EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc",
EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> Directive[RandomColor[], AbsoluteThickness[5], CapForm["Round"]]
```

[image]

**Update:** -- this is not quite correct --- (1) Reverse the edges in Collatz tree, (2) use `DepthFirstScan` get an ordered list of vertices, (3) split the list at branch points, (4) assign `θ` or `-θ` to each element of the list based on its parity, (5) `Fold` `AnglePath` on the resulting list of lists:

```
ClearAll[anglePath]
Options[anglePath] := {VertexLabels -> False, InitialCoords -> {{0, 0}, 0}};

anglePath[g_, θ_, opts : OptionsPattern[{anglePath, Graphics}]] := 
 Module[{pieces = Split[Flatten @ Reap[DepthFirstScan[g, 1, 
  {"PrevisitVertex" -> (If[Length @ VertexOutComponent[g, #, 1] == 3, 
     Sow[{#, #}], Sow[#]] &)} ]][[2, 1]], Unequal], angles, path},
  angles = θ ( Mod[pieces, 2] + 1 /. 2 -> -1);
  path = Join @@ Rest[FoldList[AnglePath[Last[#], Rest@#2] &, 
     {OptionValue[InitialCoords]}, angles]];
  Graphics[{Red,  Point @ path, Black, 
    OptionValue[VertexLabels] /. 
      {True -> MapThread[Text[Style[#, 14], #2] &, {Join @@ pieces, path} ], _ -> {}}, 
     Blue, Line@ path}, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
vk = 20;
edges = (DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Collatz[#], 2, 1]) & /@  Range[vk] // 
   Flatten // Union;
g = Graph[Reverse /@ edges];

anglePath[g, Pi/5, VertexLabels -> True, ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

```
vk = 500;
edges = (DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Collatz[#], 2, 1]) & /@  
     Range[vk] // Flatten // Union;
g = Graph[Reverse /@ edges];

anglePath[g, Pi/2, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], ImageSize -> 500, 
 ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

With `vk = 3000` and

```
 anglePath[g, 2 Pi/5, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], ImageSize -> 700, 
   ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Perhaps:

Using [this answer by Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85719/125) to construct a Collatz sequence:

```
ClearAll[Collatz]
Collatz[1] := {1}
Collatz[n_Integer]  := Prepend[Collatz[3 n + 1], n] /; OddQ[n] && n > 0
Collatz[n_Integer] := Prepend[Collatz[n/2], n] /; EvenQ[n] && n > 0

vk =  15;
edges = (DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Collatz[#], 2, 1]) & /@ Range[vk] // Flatten // Union;

g = Graph[edges, 
   GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphDrawing", "Orientation" -> Top}, 
   ImagePadding -> 10, EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[Small], 
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", AspectRatio -> 2, ImageSize -> 300];
```

We take the vertical component of a vertex as its distance to the sink vertex and the vertical distance between layers as `1`. So instead of working with angles we can work with horizontal displacements from `0` as input to the vertex layout process.

```
ClearAll[vc]
vc[g_, Δ_] := First[#] -> {Δ If[EvenQ @ First @ #, 1, -1] + Δ (Count[Rest @ #, _?EvenQ] - 
  Count[Rest @ #, _OddQ]), Length @ #} & /@ (VertexOutComponent[g, #] & /@ VertexList[g])

g2 = Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> vc[g, 1/4], 
   ImagePadding -> 10, EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[Small], 
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 2];

Row[{g, g2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Note:** For larger `vk` (e.g., `vk = 20`) some vertices will overlap.

Comment: This is a nice start, but alas cannot work for the large ($\approx 4 \cdot 10^5$) node Collatz network I want to create.  Such a network cannot be layered, as is required in your solution.  In fact, the links curve and can occasionally reverse direction, and (yes) overlap, as shown in my linked video.  I will try to modify your solution to deal with *angles*, not just horizontal offsets, but I think that will prove rather difficult.

Comment: Alas, I tried simply running your code but got lots of errors and no graph, so clearly I'm not initializing something, or something correctly.  You should be able to make a "large" graph from beginning to end with your code (e.g., $10^4$) without any memory or computation problems... right?  I'll work on this tomorrow.  Thanks for the effort... I feel we're close.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I am not able run it on graphs with more than a few thousand nodes due to cloud credit limitation on wolfram cloud.

Comment: Even 200 will suffice.  Does that work for you?  When I inspect graph g I get:  `Graph[{Partition[1, 2, 1], Partition[1, 2, 2],....`  Something is wrong there.

Comment: @David, looks like a different `Collatz` function than Sjoerd's?

Comment: You're right... I needed to use Sjoerd's.  That helped, and I got an "errored" figure much like yours, but just with the vertex numeral labels present, but no edges, and the error message "Times is not a Graphics primitive or directive."  There may be a small typo from copying.  Still working on it... getting closer!  Got it!  You had a space in `Lin e` near the bottom.  Fixed it... and reproduced your middle figure.  But that isn't like the video-linked graph I was seeking, even after playing with $\theta$ settings.  Let me keep working on it.

Comment: @David, I think I got the grouping of vertices into subpaths wrong. I will update with a fix.

Comment: Yes...  I agree the branches are incorrect.  I couldn't figure out how to fix that problem . I'm also not convinced the angle function is correct, since it doesn't seem to give the right embedded shape even for a single branch.  Everything seems to go from lower-left to upper-right under certain circumstances.  Anyway... I look forward to your update!

Comment: @David, the grouping of vertices is fixed in update 2. We get different orientations  playing with the two parameters  (reference angle `\[Phi]` and angle displacement `\[Theta]`)  Try for example: `\[Phi] = Pi/4;\[Theta] = Pi/8;` and `\[Phi] =- Pi/4;\[Theta] = Pi/8;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98595/discussion-between-david-g-stork-and-kglr).

Comment: Hi @DavidG.Stork, Just noticed your comment. I am in the chat rm if you are around.